# ping with packet size larger than 25152 failing?

Tags: ping

When I am trying to ping with packet size > 25152 I am getting 100% packet loss. can anyone please help me out on why is it happening ???

ping -c 1 -s 25153 time.nist.gov

--- ntp.glb.nist.gov ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

ping -c 1 -s 25152 time.nist.gov

PING ntp.glb.nist.gov (64.236.96.53) 25152(25180) bytes of data.
25160 bytes from dtc-nist01.ntp.aol.com (64.236.96.53): icmp_req=1 ttl=45 time=76.8 ms

--- ntp.glb.nist.gov ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 76.887/76.887/76.887/0.000 ms

Comment: Your pings are too heavy and are dropped along the way, either because of a hardware not handling it well or because of firewall rules.

Comment: I get a timeout - perhaps that is really the problem?

Comment: yes I also got timeout but why I am getting that ???

Comment: pinging www.google.com works for me from one Linux host up to `-s 1442` while on the same host, time.nist.gov only works up to `-s 1472` (Ethernet MTU - IPv4 and ICMP header). On OSX, ping with `-s` larger than 8184 (8192 - size of ICMP header) even says: `sendto: Message too long`, even though in principle long ping packets can be fragmented... So I would agree with @Puciek , this depends a lot on filter settings of routers / switches in between you and the destination host.

Comment: @AndreHolzner I agree. The largest packet size is varying with host to which we are pinging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [very quick google shows](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2005-January/071173.html) you are exceeding amount of fragments (data) that fits into one packet. In order to support that you would have to change configuration on your machine (and possibly the remote) to utilize it.

Answer (score -1):

No, it’s not because of hardware, it’s because of IP restriction or it could be because the data choking happening in the router that you were pinging. It will consider large packets as data packets and drops it. If you try small packets, it never shows you any drop because the device will prioratized the input as voice or video.